# Resume encoding or re-encoding video after a power loss in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a php script that reads from database and converts videos using ffmpeg.

Sometimes the power goes off and my server turns of suddenly.

What should I do to re-encode the video that was being converted while the power loss occurred?

The whole process should be automatic.

Comment: Plug your server into an [uninterruptible power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply).

Comment: sir, right now, i cant afford a ups. so i am looking for an alternative way.

Comment: Before encoding / decoding, write the path of the video to a file.  After encoding / decoding, delete the path of the video.  When starting your application, check for a path of a video in the file.  If the path is there encode / decode the video again.

Comment: It worked @GilbertLeBlanc. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can want just add a `flag` field to your video table in the database with default `0` value, then after convert completed, update `flag` field record set to `1`.
Add PHP script into cronjob, and when run it again after restart, just convert video record with `flag=0`.

Or you can stored video path must be converted into file or database as queue. and after each convert, remove the path video from queue.